# Negating a word in the accusative case with an indefinite article

Tags: article, grammatical-number, negation, indefinite-pronoun

As I understand it, in the accusative case, masculine words change *ein* to *einen.*
Thus, when trying to negate the word, *kein* becomes *keinen.*
For e.g.:

> Es gibt einen See. → Es gibt keinen See.

I thus would expect the following change in case of a plural:

> Es gibt Clubs. → Es gibt keinen Clubs.

Instead, I learnt that I was wrong and the following is correct:

> Es gibt Clubs. → Es gibt keine Clubs.

Why? Do plurals also not change in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I posted this declination table of *keiner* as an answer to another question just yesterday

```
            Singular                Plural
            m       f       n
Nominative  keiner  keine   kein    keine
Genitive    keines  keiner  keines  keiner 
Dative      keinem  keiner  keinem  keinen
Accusative  keinen  keine   kein    keine
```

There is no greater logic in this, you have to memorize all 16 forms.

Comment: There is a *small* bit of logic in these declinations. For instance, neuter words never have a marked accusative - the accusative is always identical to the nominative. And plural words are never inflected for gender (and therefore, the plural accusative is also never marked, since the generic plural encompasses the neuter gender). It's just that the amount of regularity is not big enough to be worth teaching - most people find it easier just to memorize everything.